# MySql alternative to PHP date interval

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by, intervals

I'm trying to create a report which is kinda complicated(at least to me) because it will allow the user to choose an interval for the report, and group by smaller intervals e.g. every day, every week, every two weeks, every month, every quarter and so on. I found how I can generate interval table columns using PHP DatePeriod and and DateInterval functions, but now I'm stuck to convert to MySql in order to match the db columns with html table columns generated by PHP.

```
<select class="form-control" id="columns" name="columns" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1 day" selected="">Each day</option>
    <option value="1 week">Each week</option>
    <option value="1 month">Each month</option>
    <option value="3 months">Each quarter</option>
    <option value="1 year">Each year</option>
</select>
```

This is the select option for choosing how the report is gonna be grouped and:

```
$cols = array();
$colsIdentifiers = array();
$start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(request('start_date'));
$end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(request('end_date'));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString(request('columns'));
$period = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $end_date);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
   $cols[] = $dt->format("d-m-Y");
   $colsIdentifiers [] = $dt->format("dmY");
}
```

This is the php code to generate the cols.

How can do the same but in Mysql??

Comment: What you are looking for is the DATE_SUB function https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp

Comment: We know precisely nothing about your schema. You must be wanting the psychic forum

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can only use the `BETWEEN` SQL command to solve your problem. Your database don't need to know what are these importants dates, but only persists these data.

Try do it:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, name, something";
$sql .= "FROM table";
$sql .= "WHERE datefield BETWEEN :minvalue AND :maxvalue";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':minvalue' => $minLimit, ':maxvalue' => $maxLimit]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();


foreach($data as $item) {
    // do something with your new set.
}
```

Hope that help you.